# Conway's law translation - festgelegt, eingeschränkt

Tags: translation

From Wikipedia - https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesetz_von_Conway

> “Organizations which design systems […] are constrained to produce
>   designs which are copies of the communication structures of these
>   organizations.”

.

> „Organisationen, die Systeme entwerfen, […] sind auf Entwürfe
>   festgelegt, welche die Kommunikationsstrukturen dieser Organisationen
>   abbilden.“

I want to stress "constrained" which "festgelegt" does not seem to meet. Would "eingeschränkt" be a better word? Or "gezwungen"?

> „Organisationen, die Systeme entwerfen, […] sind auf Entwürfe
>   eingeschränkt, welche die Kommunikationsstrukturen dieser
>   Organisationen abbilden.“

My German Level is B1/B2. I'm to give a talk, in English, on this topic to a bunch of Germans and I want them to be be sure to understand because it's a bit nuanced. This German Translation seems quite different from the original English but obviously I'm not qualified to make that assertion.

Ta, Andrew

Answer (score 3):

As a native German, to put the stress, I would use "zwingen". And by the way, you forgot to translate "produce".

> „Organisationen, die Systeme entwerfen, […] sind gezwungen, Entwürfe
>   zu erstellen, die die Kommunikationsstrukturen dieser
>   Organisationen abbilden.“

Comment: That already feels better for me.

Comment: +1, but … sind **dazu** gezwungen … would sound even better.

Comment: @Janka: Nö, tut's nicht.

Answer (score 3):

The actual meaning of constraint in this context is **Beschränkung**. The sentence would then be:

> „Organisationen, die Systeme entwerfen, […] sind auf Entwürfe **beschränkt**, welche die Kommunikationsstrukturen dieser Organisationen abbilden.“

This is the correct use instead of **eingeschränkt**, which doesn't come with the **auf**. It describes a limitation or boundaries.

For **Festlegen** the best translation I can come up with in this context is *to be set on something*. It is probably a bit weak and it doesn't quite fit the context.

**Gezwungen** implies a force. So the organisations would be forced to create only those designs.

I would probably use **beschränkt** for the translation and add another sentence to show how strong organiations get limited by their own communication structures.

Comment: I share your reservations about _gezwungen_. It sounds good in the sentence, but on closer inspection doesn't seem like that good a fit semantically. I have some concerns about the  _sind auf Entwürfe beschränkt_ part, though. As Adrian - correctly, I think - observed, it's not obvious, in German as well as in English, in what way an organisation would be constrained to drafts, hence the verb, _produce_, should probably not be omitted in the translation. Maybe something like _sind darauf beschränkt, Entwürfe hervorzubringen, ..._ would be an option.

Comment: "gezwungen" ist semantically fine if the "force" is the constraint emerging from the communication structure. it is also one of the most common translations of "to be constrained"

Comment: @Adrian Well, of course you can construe a metaphorical force but I would proffer that the word is not commonly used under those circumstances. Beispiel: ein Quadrat mit Kantenlänge x. Sind Kreise, die innerhalb dieses Quadrats liegen, _gezwungen_, höchstens den Durchmesser x zu haben? Ich würde das nicht sagen. So ähnlich scheint mir der Fall im Beispiel zu liegen, wo ebenfalls auf eine (behauptete) logische Notwendigkeit abgestellt wird.

Comment: I'd agree that "beschränken" would be the best literal translation. But in this specific case a simple "können" might describe the constraint better: "Organisationen, die Systeme entwerfen, können nur Entwürfe hervorbringen, die die Kommunikationsstrukturen innerhalb der Organisation reproduzieren."

Comment: The idea of constraints in this sense is rather about some kind of limitation, rather than a force. With *beschränkt* the sentence becomes an emotional  rather neutral statement. The suggestion *können nur Entwürfe hervorbringen* puts a good focus on the lack of ability to produce something else and expresses the issue rather well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the aspect of being forced. We use Conway's Law in this translation.

> "Die Struktur der Organisation beeinflußt die Struktur der Systementwürfe."

or simplier

> Architektur folgt Struktur.